# Using consul's DNS interface within docker containers

Tags: networking, dns, docker, consul

I've got a consul agent running on my host machine, and a couple of services running inside docker containers. I'm using 'gliderlabs/registrator' to discover these services and register them with the local consul agent.

The consul agent is configured to accept connections from everywhere (`"client_addr": "0.0.0.0"` option), which I can "prove" by doing `dig @172.17.42.1 -p 8600 someservice.service.consul` from the host machine.

Problem is that I don't seem to be able to do the same from within the containers, the dig request just times out and I can't `curl` it either. I do pass `--dns 172.17.42.1`. Any ideas?

Note: I want to avoid using `--net=host` if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I was hitting the same roadblock, and your setup and mine look really similar (I'm running Consul standalone rather than as a Docker container).

I am also against using `--net=host` !!!.

What made it work in my case was:

**a)** I've created a `config.json` for Consul, and inside of it I've set up  the `ports.dsn` property to use port 53 (DNS default).

You can't use 8600 inside of Docker containers, this is because the `docker run --dns` argument does not allow you to give a port.

**b)** I've used the LAN (private) IP of the host as the `--dns` value. I've tried with other values before (`0.0.0.0`, public IP and `127.0.0.1`) but those weren't working.

**c)** Optional: You can add `--dns-search="service.consul"` to the `docker run` so you can have shorter domain names (i.e avoid having to write the `service.consul` part).

Once inside of the container, you can execute a `nslookup ubuntu.service.consul` provided that's the service name you have for 
that container.

**Important notes**:

- You need to expose ports (i.e `-P` or `-p` flag) on the container for `registrator` to pick them up. If you don't share a port, `registrator` will silently ignore the container.
- It is nice to setup a hostname (using `-h` flag).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Curious, is it possible to configure consul to register domains like: redis.internal.example.com. Where 'redis' is the service, 'internal' the subdomain for internal services, and example.com our domain name. I am not the fun of `service.consul` suffix.